# Why to use doGet or doPost in servlets

Tags: java, servlets

Why do I need doGet or doPost methods?

Can't I write everything in service method?

Comment: What is your objection to using doGet and doPost?

Answer (score 3):

> Can't I write everything in service method?

Yes, you can, if you like; just override `HttpServlet`'s implementation of `service` in your subclass, which dispatches to `doPost`, `doGet`, etc., as necessary. I wouldn't *recommend* it (the verbs really are different things and nearly always require different implementations), but you *can* do it.

Without having a magic view into the minds of the people who designed `HttpServlet`, I can only speculate that as different verbs are pretty different operations, they thought it would be helpful to have the verbs automatically dispatched to specific named methods.

Note that if you override `service` in `HttpServlet`, you may find that toolkits or extensions won't work properly (this is entirely hypothetical), if they're expecting you to use `doPost` and such instead.